# Linking multiple existing work items to queued build (from Azure Devops SDK)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure Devops REST API, I want to link a task\bug\story (that already exists) when triggering a build. How do I do that?

`checkInTicket` might be a solution, but it is [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#uri-parameters).

*Payload based on Merlin's response worked:*

```cs
var payload = new object[] {
    new {
        op = "add",
        path = "/relations/-",
        value =
        new {
            rel = "ArtifactLink",
            url = $"vstfs:///Build/Build/{buildId}",
            attributes = new
            {
                name = "Build"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Link the exists work items into build? Or create the new work item? They are achieved in different way.

Comment: link an existing one. let me update the question

Comment: Soory for late response. I provide my suggestion into below answer. Hope one of those 2 approaches could help you achieve what you want. Feel free to leave comment if you still facing any puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **1. Approach 1**

Same with the UI operation, to link the exists work item to build, just need to update one option in build definition:

This is the api:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/definitions/{definition id}?api-version=5.0-preview.6
```

In its request body, please focus on below script part:

```
"options": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "inputs": {
        "branchFilters": "[\"+refs/heads/*\"]",
        "additionalFields": "{}"
      },
      "definition": {
        "id": "5d58cc01-7c75-450c-be18-a388ddb129ec"
      }
    }
  ]
```

The `enabled` represent whether it will create links to work items which linked to associated changes after the build completed. To achieve what you want, here, please set the `enabled` value as `true`. The id value is fixed and represent this option, so here do not worry about this id value.

When you updating the build definition by this method, do not forget increment the revision in request body. `revision` increment means update the definition as a new revision. or the **update** action would not actually succeed.

But, what you should concerned is this update should finished before the build triggered. Thus it will create link to the exists WIT automatically after the build finished.

Also, this would only add this build link to work item which **associate with the changes**.

---

- **2. Approach 2**

If the above is not what you want, and you just want to link work item to build while the build is triggered. Afraid to say, there's no such direct API could finish that.

You may need to use 2 APIs: one of it is [queue build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), and another API is add this [build link to work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#add-a-link).

The request body sample of add build link to work item:

```
[
    {
        "op": "test",
        "path": "/rev",
        "value": "2"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value":
        {
            "rel": "ArtifactLink",
            "url": "vstfs:///Build/Build/{the build id that you just queued}"
        }
    }
]
```

This method need you get the generated `BuildId` after you queue the build, and then pass it to the `workitem` API. Different with the approach 1, in this method, you can customize the work item id which you want to add the build link to.

Comment: wow thank you for that response. Two request would absolutely work for me, but I'm unable to form a working request. Kindly see follow up in question text. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @skfd 401 means header token not correct. Did you ever confirmed the PATtoken scope? Is it not expired, right? I am out of my office. Will give you exactly test result when I back to my office.

Comment: same token works for creating\triggering build, so I feel it is valid. Could you please test that payload on Azure Devops?

Comment: @skfd, I test your script on my side. No any 401 issue and it works fine. This is my scripts: https://imgur.com/a/ZYQafBX . This is my build result: https://imgur.com/a/cmbVkM4 If still has 401 issue, please re-generate a new token with **full access** scope.

Comment: my bad, I fexed the access and it worked. Had to tweak your payload a little though. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @skfd Awesome! It’s my pleasure to help you